# local server connection to remote mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have found this question here and around internet for few times, but none answered helped me.

So I have a local apache+php server and trying to connect to remote mysql database. But script returns me error and in error log i see:

```
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): Premature end of data (mysqlnd_wireprotocol.c:553) in D:\\_SERVER\\_WWW\\project\\api\\classes\\database.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): OK packet 1 bytes shorter than expected in D:\\_SERVER\\_WWW\\project\\api\\classes\\database.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  mysql_connect(): mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file in D:\\_SERVER\\_WWW\\project\\api\\classes\\database.php on line 13
```

The script for connection (just the part connecting to server):

```
function db_connect(){
    // Connect to the database server
    $connection = mysql_connect("server.com:3306","username","password",true);
    if (!$connection){
        echo "Could not connect to the Database server, please check your settings";
        die;
    }
...
}
```

The trick with setting PASSWORD did not work for me, can someone please help me ?

Thank you

Comment: If remote connection is not allowed you would not be able to connect to server directly.

Comment: right? i think that remote connection settings should be fine, but dunno what is the problem here

Comment: instead of echoing a fixed string, echo out the actual reason for the error "if (!$connection) { die(mysql_error()); }`. It'll tell you what's wrong, if only you'd let it.

Comment: As I expected, its the same error like in logs 'mysqlnd cannot connect to MySQL 4.1+ using the old insecure authentication. Please use an administration tool to reset your password with the command SET PASSWORD = PASSWORD('your_existing_password'). This will store a new, and more secure, hash value in mysql.user. If this user is used in other scripts executed by PHP 5.2 or earlier you might need to remove the old-passwords flag from your my.cnf file'

Answer (score 0):

The remote needs to allow incoming MySQL connections from your server's IP address. This can be added within a the MySQL config file from the remote server.

For more information in how to edit the config file, here are detailed instructions.
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Answer (score 0):

The firewall needs to port-forward to the server:port on the respective system,
which requires a static or dhcp address reservation for the mysql server machine